# TextBox does not stretch horizontally in UWP

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml

[image]

The Blue Part is my textbox and red is my relative panel. The relative panel is placed in a list view

```
<ListView RelativePanel.Below="Line" Name="SubTasksListView" Margin="10,10,10,0"   HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"   ItemsSource="{x:Bind subtasks}" IsItemClickEnabled="True" ItemClick="ItemClick"   ItemTemplate="{StaticResource SubTaskDataTemplate}"/>



 <DataTemplate x:DataType="data:ZTask" x:Key="SubTaskDataTemplate">
 <RelativePanel Margin="10,10,20,10"  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"  VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Background="Red" >
            <TextBox Background="Aqua" BorderThickness="0,0,0,0" BorderBrush="#8888" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"  KeyDown="Box_KeyDown" RelativePanel.AlignLeftWithPanel="True" Name="SubTaskTitle" PlaceholderText="+ Subtask" FontSize="16"   Margin="0"/>
            <Line Name="Line" Stretch="Fill" Margin="10 0 0 0" Stroke="#8888" X2="1" Opacity="0.2" RelativePanel.Below="SubTaskTitle"/>
</RelativePanel>
</DataTemplate>
```

I have tried HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" and HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" but it doesn't work.Please Help me solve this issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe, this is due the lack of exact alignment instructions, as Relative Panel is a bit conservative to minimize potential conflicts between inner elements and their layout desires. So, could you try to explicitly set both left and right alignment, like this:

```
... RelativePanel.AlignLeftWithPanel="True" RelativePanel.AlignRightWithPanel="True" ...
```

Upd: and yes, it seems in your case the layout could be simplified by using Grid element because there are too few inner controls (just two) so it's not an issue to position them.

Comment: Works Well Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Using Grid instead of relative panel worked for me

```
 <Grid Margin="10,10,20,10"  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"  VerticalAlignment="Stretch" >
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition />
                <RowDefinition />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <TextBox  BorderThickness="0,0,0,0" BorderBrush="#8888" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"  KeyDown="Box_KeyDown"  Name="SubTaskTitle" PlaceholderText="+ Subtask" FontSize="16"   Margin="0"/>
            <Line Name="Line" Stretch="Fill" Margin="10 0 0 0" Stroke="#8888" X2="1" Opacity="0.2" Grid.Row="1"/>
        </Grid>
```

But I still am not able to figure out why it does not work with relative panel, Someone please post the answer using relative panel.

Comment: hey in above snippet looks like you are adding task(appointment) to user calendar or google/iOS calendar ??

Comment: No bro it's different

Comment: do you have any idea how to add task to google calendar in uwp(desktop application) ? [link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58006274/11362349)